# Can a method later on become static?

Tags: c++, oop

Let's say I have a base class which happens to be abstract.
I declare a method as:

```
virtual void movement() = 0;
```

And the question is, when I create a class which inherits from this base class, can I re-implement this function as a static one?

Comment: No, this can't be done. What do you actually want to achieve? Why do you need a static reimplementation?

Comment: No, but you can have the implementation call a static function, or simply not use `this` explicitly.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here, but if you want this method to be accessable staticly you may create a public static reference and access the method via that.
Maybe like this:

```
class Clazz : BaseClazz
{
    public static Clazz* instance;

    public Clazz()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public void movement() override
    {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

and then call

```
Clazz::instance.movement();
```

Comment: `movement` is still a member method. `doSomething` is this static. Does this have a memory leak

Comment: yes, movement is still a member method, but it can be accessed via the static pointer to the object

Comment: Java does not have pointers not does C#. So what language is this?

Comment: It's not a specific language, it's just a way to visualize things. Btw, why that downvote? This is a perfectly valid solution to solve the problem, isn't it?

Comment: One question - Can you have multiple objects of the same class?

Comment: Yes you can have multiple objects of the same class.

Comment: But you only have one value for `instance`? i.e. one object

Comment: Yes, in this case only the instance of the class stored in the "instance" variable is accessible, but as xjose97x said, he wants the method to be accessible in a static way.